# Non-Entity Class Requiring [Key] Attribute

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am getting `EntityType 'ScheduleNote' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.` for a POCO that has nothing to do with Entity Framework.  Does EF require that I define a [Key] for every class in the project whether or not it deals with the database?

UPDATE:

Here is the ScheduleNote code:

```
using System;

namespace Domain
{
    public class ScheduleNote
    {
        public string NoteId { get; set; }
        public NoteTypeEnum Type { get; set; }
        public string TypeFK { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string AuthorName { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime InsertDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DeleteDate { get; set; }
        public bool IsPublic { get; set; }
        public bool IsModified { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    }

    public enum NoteTypeEnum
    {
        INSIGHT_EVENT = 0,
        INSIGHT_SERIES = 1,
        INSIGHT_TEAM = 2
    }
}
```

So when the application starts up (ASP.NET Web API), the very first call to the database using EF (which is not related to this class) errors with the "no key defined" error.  The class is not defined in my DbContext or anywhere.  It just exists in the project and EF does not like that it doesn't have a [Key] attribute.

I could just add the attribute and move on but that does not explain "why" I would need to do so.  My understanding was that new or legacy code would not have to be altered with the introduction of EF.

Comment: No. it definitely does not. Please post some code and the indicate where in code you get this error.

Comment: @PraveenPaulose, I added some more code.

Comment: Do you have *any* classes that reference `ScheduleNote`?

Comment: To further debug it, can you add a Key and then check if a table ScheduleNote is being created in your database. If it does then it is being referenced from one of your Entity classes and causing the issue.

Comment: @PraveenPaulose, I changed NoteId to ScheduleNoteId and the error went away.  To me that says that EF still looks at this class as an Entity under its responsibility now that there is a property that matches the "Key" requirements for the class.

Comment: You cal also right-click on the class name and select "Find All References" to see where the class is being referenced.

Comment: @ErikPhilips, actually I do.  It is a property (an IList) on one class.

Comment: Where do you _use_ the class?  Is it a property of some other class that is part of the EF model?  To answer the question EF does not require that _all_ classes have a PK - only those that are referenced (either directly or indirectly) by a DbContext.

Comment: Since it is referenced in your IList, it will attempt to create an Entity and that is why it gives you that error then

Comment: @FrankO Is that class in EF - or is it referenced by an EF class?

Comment: Don't you want this class ScheduleNote in your database?

Comment: @ErikPhilips, Looks like the reference to the class was the cause of the problem.  I will give you credit if you make an answer.

Comment: @PraveenPaulose, no. It is not supposed to be in the database in its current form.

Comment: In that case you can put an [NotMapped] attribute on top of the IList. Does this solve your issue?

Comment: @PraveenPaulose, the removal of the reference in the separate class was the appropriate step to take (it was left there by accident).  [NotMapped] is very useful but in this case is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use that Class as a related entity in some way, you'll need to use the `[NotMapped]` attribute on the property to let EF know you don't want it to auto-wireup the property.  Or simply remove it as a reference.